# MSVC can't find its libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

For some purpose that is not really important I used MSVC 2012 in console mode (Windows 8x64) and when I tried to compile "Hello, World!" it didn't find its stabdard library and linker couldn't find some of its lib-files. So in the end I managed to configure both compile and link commands to make them work properly:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" -c main.cpp /I               

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include"
```

and for link:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\link.exe"
main.obj
/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib"
/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86"
```

To sum up I want to know, how can they be configured so that cl found its headers and link found those libs. Please consider that I'm going to use them in Qt Creator, where they don't work and I've just found a way of getting them to work but from outside of Creator and I need to do it by Creators' means (nmake or jom options that is).

Comment: The environment must be setup correctly to let the compiler and linker find stuff without you explicitly giving the required directories.  You'd normally do so by using the Visual Studio Command Prompt or by calling the vc/vcvarsall.bat command file.  Maybe you ought to focus on why QT Creator is having trouble, plenty of questions about that already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
call %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

in your command line window. This sets up a usable environment.